# To draw Chain complexes?

Tags: math-mode, diagrams

[image]I have to draw matrices over long arrows in LaTex for homology purpose. I do not know the code. Please help me in the same.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. Please, provide at least a sketch, what you like to draw. And TeX-maker seems to be an editor, not LaTeX program or package. For help you, you need provide more information ...

Comment: Hard to tell from your one-liner what you really want/need. Is it something like commutative diagrams, see e.g. [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200204/110998)?

Comment: I have uploaded the sketch. Hope you guys may help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `matrix`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
0 \leftarrow \Bbbk
 \xleftarrow[\partial_0]{%
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1&1&1&1&1
    \end{bmatrix}}%
    \Bbbk^5 
    \xleftarrow[\partial_1]{%
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1&-1&0&0&0\\
         1&0&-1&-1&0\\
        0&1&1&0&-1\\
        -0&0&0&1&1\\
        0&0&0&0&0
        \end{bmatrix}}
    \Bbbk^5 
    \xleftarrow[\partial_2]{%
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1\\-1\\1\\0\\0
        \end{bmatrix}}
    \Bbbk 
    \leftarrow 0
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

and `array`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
0 \leftarrow \Bbbk
 \xleftarrow[\partial_0]{%
    \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
        1&1&1&1&1
    \end{array}\right]}%
    \Bbbk^5 
    \xleftarrow[\partial_1]{%
        \left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
        -1&-1&0&0&0\\
         1&0&-1&-1&0\\
        0&1&1&0&-1\\
        -0&0&0&1&1\\
        0&0&0&0&0
        \end{array}\right]}
    \Bbbk^5 
    \xleftarrow[\partial_2]{%
        \left[\begin{array}{r}
        1\\-1\\1\\0\\0
        \end{array}\right]}
    \Bbbk 
    \leftarrow 0
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `bsmallmatrix` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
0 \leftarrow \Bbbk
 \xleftarrow[\partial_0]{%
    \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        1&1&1&1&1
    \end{bsmallmatrix}}%
    \Bbbk^5 
    \xleftarrow[\partial_1]{%
        \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        -1&-1&0&0&0\\
         1&0&-1&-1&0\\
        0&1&1&0&-1\\
        -0&0&0&1&1\\
        0&0&0&0&0
        \end{bsmallmatrix}}
    \Bbbk^5 
    \xleftarrow[\partial_2]{%
        \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        1\\-1\\1\\0\\0
        \end{bsmallmatrix}}
    \Bbbk 
    \leftarrow 0
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use `smallmatrix`